# Gradle: IntelliJ like 'export' dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, gradle, android-studio

Is there an 'export' dependencies version of IntelliJ idea in gradle?

On IntelliJ IDEA if I have module A dependent on module B and module B dependent on  module C, then module B's dependencies will only be exported to module A if **exported is set to true**.

I am currently writing a script to convert my IntelliJ projects to a Gradle project. How does Gradle handle transitive dependencies in the buildscript when writing:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':DependentProject') // exported = true, but how?
}
```

**?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In Gradle, module B's dependencies will be automatically exported to A, although the details of how this works are different (e.g. there is conflict resolution).

Comment: if they're automatically exported, then how do I disable export?

Comment: Gradle's dependency management works differently than IntelliJ's, and there is no direct equivalent of IntelliJ's "export yes/no". To propose a solution I'd need to know what exactly you are building, and why you don't want to export a dependency. I'd first concentrate on porting the rest of the build.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes, I should just configure the dependencies so that there is never a need to 'not export' a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do might be to apply the `idea` plugin in your script and then run `gradle idea`. Then simply double-click the .ipr file to open the project.

When you do that, IntelliJ IDEA will fetch direct and transitive dependencies--assuming they're declared properly and can be found.